# Is it possible to solve following integral with partial-fraction decomposition?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I have a integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{-x^2+4x+4}{x^2-4}~dx$$
Which I changed to
$$\int_0^1\frac{-x^2+4x+4}{(x-2)(x+2)}~dx$$
But I don't know how to change numerator to have lesser polynom degree than the denominator to use partial-fraction decomposition.

Comment: Use long division first

Comment: Start by dividing $x^2-4$ into $-x^2+4x+4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{-x^2+4x+4}{x^2-4}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{4x}{x^2-4}-1\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\frac2{x-2}+\frac2{x+2}-1\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First divide numerator by denominator, *then* apply partial fraction decomposition to the resulting fraction from the remainder divided by the denominator (and integrate the quotient part separately).

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is

$$8-(x-2)^2$$

so the integrand is

$$\begin{align}\frac{8-(x-2)^2}{(x-2)(x+2)} &= \frac{8}{(x-2)(x+2)} - \frac{x-2}{x+2} \\ &= 2 \left (\frac1{x-2} - \frac1{x+2} \right ) - \frac{4}{x+2} +1 \end{align}$$

You should be able to go from here...